# Golang Generic Interface Implementation

Tags: go, generics, interface

[Image of example input output grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AraTv.png)

So I am trying to implement a piece of code in golang where we have compile time assurance but also structural flexibility.

I have a case where I have a 9x9 grid essentially of operations that can be performed with 3 different options of inputs, and 3 different options of output.  And a single operation would only have 1 return type or 1 output type

The inputs have a lot of common fields and then 1 different field so I wrapped it up like:

```
type Input interface {
  Input1 | Input2 | Input3
}

type Input1 {
  CommonField int
  CommonField2 int
  UniqueField int
}

type Input2 {
  CommonField int
  CommonField2 int
  UniqueField2 string
}
```

And then the output is the same way:

```
type Output interface {
  Output1 | Output2 | Output3 
}
```

And then I want it so that explicit implementations can be made using exact types so what I was working on was

```
type Operator[I Input, O Output] interface {
  Call(I) O
}
```

And my goal is I can implement them concretely with correct type checking

```
type SpecialOperator1 struct {
}

func (SpecialOperator1) Call(Input1) Output2 {
  // code here
}
```

And then have some place where I can have instance of Operator without needing to just pass around SpecialOperator1 type everywhere

There are also cases where an operator may work on more than 1 type for an input OR output

```
type Operator2[I Input] struct {}
func (Operator2[I) Call(I) Output2
```

But I am really struggling with how to mash all these together seamlessly in golang

Comment: Based on the information you gave, my instinct would be to do this without generics. Generics would be useful if you apply same/similar syntactic construct on multiple types, but this looks like a different operation for each type combination. Correct me please if I misunderstood.

Comment: I do not think you misunderstood.

I agree that it could be done without generics,  My goal on using generics was to create a limited / but flexible forced contract on operations.

So if someone (not me) works on it, then it is only considered a valid "operation" if it takes in one of these 3 types, has a function called `Call` and spits out one of those 3 outputs.

I can't think of a way to achieve that with regular interfaces without generics :(

Comment: Do you really need an interface? An operation is `func [I Input, O Output] Operator(I) O`

Comment: It's unclear, from your description, *what* exactly you are struggling with. It seems you do have a solution that works. Are you asking how to accomplish the second use case? *cases where an operator may work on more than 1 type for an input OR output*